# Jenkins-Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a jenkins pipeline where I am trying to scan an angular website for sonarqube and I have encountered this error:

```
ERROR: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
ERROR:     throw err;
ERROR:     ^
ERROR: 
ERROR: Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
ERROR:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
ERROR:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
ERROR:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
ERROR:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
ERROR:     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\SonarQube\ajbic-client-app\.scannerwork\sonarts-bundle\node_modules\tslint\lib\language\walker\blockScopeAwareRuleWalker.js:20:10)
ERROR:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
ERROR:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
ERROR:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
ERROR:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
ERROR:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
ERROR: Failed to find 'typescript' module. Please check, NODE_PATH contains location of global 'typescript' or install locally in your project
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
```

my setup in jenkins is like this:

```
steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('Dev-build-01') {
            bat "cd D:/SonarQube/abcd-webapp"
            bat "rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json"
            bat "npm install"
            bat "C:/Jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQubeScanner/Net/bin/sonar-scanner.bat -D sonar.projectKey=abcd-webapp -D sonar.sources=src -D sonar.login=667723c08ecfe0fc0d5c0e91bdd5c4b219e851e7 -D sonar.projectBaseDir=D:/SonarQube/abcd-webapp"
        }
            timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
              //   waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
                }
            }   
         }
```

I ahve done the usual stuff, installing typescript(download and via npm) but everytime I am getting the same error.
Also a strange thing that happens is when I remove the stage and save, the pipeline still goes through the analysis.

Anyone have an idea of what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours pondering, I come to the solution, and before let me explain the cause. This project is downloaded from git(bitbucket), in the solution we never allow node_modules to be checked in. So in this instance node_modules doesn't exist. Secondly the problem(this is out of my control), There is no instance of bash command installed, rather someone decided to install powershell plugin and i have to deal with it.
solution was to add powershell in my script and the final result is

```
steps {
    withSonarQubeEnv('Dev-build-01') {
 powershell '''
        cd D:/SonarQube/abcd-webapp
        rmdir /q/s node_modules 
del package-lock.json
        npm install
'''
        bat "C:/Jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQubeScanner/Net/bin/sonar-scanner.bat -D sonar.projectKey=abcd-webapp -D sonar.sources=src -D sonar.login=667723c08ecfe0fc0d5c0e91bdd5c4b219e851e7 -D sonar.projectBaseDir=D:/SonarQube/abcd-webapp"
    }
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          //   waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            }
        }   
     }
```

And finally my pipeline was fixed.